# TikZ, draw along a path

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node, intersections, tikz-path

I have two semi-circumferences with an intersection point defined as `E`. I want to use different line style/color along them.

For this purpose, first I used `path` to define the semi-circumferences. Now I would like to draw:

- a line **along the semi-circumference** `orig1--A`, between `orig1` and the intersection point `E`;
- a line **along the semi-circumference** `orig2--B`, between `orig2` and the intersection point `E`.

I tried with

```
\draw[-] (orig1) to node {} (E);
```

but of course this plots a straight line between `orig1` and `E`. I want the line to follow the semi-circumference, instead.

Is it possible to do this? If yes, how?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes,arrows,arrows.meta,calc,decorations.pathreplacing,through,intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (orig1) at (0,0);

\path [name path=orig1--A, line width=0.5mm, red] (orig1) arc[start angle=0, end angle=180, radius=5cm] coordinate (A);
\coordinate (orig2) at ($(orig1)!0.5!(A)$);
\path [name path=orig2--B, line width=0.5mm, red] (orig2) arc[start angle=0, end angle=180, radius=5cm] coordinate (B);

\path [name intersections={of=orig1--A and orig2--B,by=E}];
\node at (E)[circle,fill,red] {};
%\coordinate (C) at (intersection of orig1--A and orig2--B);

\draw[-] (orig1) to node {} (E);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example is easy to obtain the necessary angles, but that wont always be true. So probably the best approach is using the `spath3` library, cut the paths in their components and then drawing only the needed one.

Something like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.618mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,spath3}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (orig1) at (0,0);
\path [draw,spath/save=orig1--A, line width=0.5mm, red] (orig1) arc[start angle=0, end angle=180, radius=5cm] coordinate (A);
\coordinate (orig2) at ($(orig1)!0.5!(A)$);
\path [draw,spath/save=orig2--B, line width=0.5mm, red] (orig2) arc[start angle=0, end angle=180, radius=5cm] coordinate (B);
\path [draw,name intersections={of=orig1--A and orig2--B,by=E}];
\node at (E)[circle,fill,red] {};
% computing the angles
\draw[line width=1.5mm,teal] (orig1) arc[start angle=0, end angle=120, radius=5cm] arc[start angle=60, end angle=180, radius=5cm];
% with spath3
\tikzset
{% spath3 operatios:
   spath/split at intersections={orig1--A}{orig2--B},
   spath/get components of={orig1--A}\Acpts,
   spath/get components of={orig2--B}\Bcpts
}
\draw[line width=0.5mm,yellow,
      spath/use=\getComponentOf\Acpts{1},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\Bcpts{2},weld}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, in this case maybe the angle can be computed, but I prefer the more general solution with `spath3`.